# ¿Por que al presionar un botón se borran las fechas del datetimepicker en webform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap, aspx

Selecciono las fechas del datetimepicker al momento de consultar me trae los datos en el gridview pero se borran las fechas.

Aqui selecciono las fechas y consulto
[image: Aqui selecciono las fechas y consulto]

Muestra los datos pero se borran las fechas
[image: Muestra los datos pero se borran las fechas]

Comment: Podría adjuntar el código que se ejecuta al presionar el botó de lo contrario no hay mucho que se pueda identificar en el porqué del comportamiento no esperado.

Comment: El boton es tipo submit? si es asi cambialo a button